# Example open source microservices applications

Tags: microservices

I'm looking for open source applications that demonstrate the [microservices](http://martinfowler.com/articles/microservices.html) pattern. In particular, I'd like to find one or more applications that can be spun up on real cloud environment up (but with fake data and requests) to demonstrate real-world deployment mechanics.

Unfortunately, I haven't found any good options yet. I'll note that [Discourse](https://www.discourse.org/) is a modern 3-tier application, using Rails API, Ember.js, Postgres, and Redis, but it still is much closer to a monolith than an example of microservices. The closest I've found so far is https://github.com/kbastani/spring-cloud-microservice-example but that is more of a framework than an actual application that delivers data.

Comment: *Disclaimer - my company contracts for Warewolf*

Warewolf is an opensource application that you can also access via a VM in Azure. It's more of a microservices builder than what you are looking for, but may be of interest.

https://warewolf.io
https://github.com/Warewolf-ESB/Warewolf-ESB

Answer (score 1):

Not your typical CRUD app but [Deis](https://github.com/deis/workflow) (a PaaS) uses REST APIs mostly to communicate between services. [Peatio](https://github.com/peatio/peatio) has a bunch of services that communicate asynchronously through a message queue.

Comment: Thanks. I am chatting with Gabe Monroy of Deis.

Comment: Your question inspired me to start https://github.com/olalonde/awesome-microservice-archs , if you find more examples, I'd appreciate if you can write them down there :)

Comment: Thanks. Please see https://www.weave.works/sock-shop-microservices-demo-application/ and the CNCF work we're doing here: https://github.com/cncf/demo

Comment: Thanks. Looks interesting! Unfortunately, it looks like the code for  weave.works/sock-shop-microservices-demo-application a isn't available (at least, I couldn't find it).

Comment: Here's the code: https://github.com/microservices-demo/microservices-demo

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft provides a demo webshop application based on .NET Core showing how to apply the microservices pattern:
https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers

There is also an ebook available: https://aka.ms/microservicesebook

Answer (score 0):

this [lagom application example](https://github.com/lagom/online-auction-java) is a microservices application written in [Lagom](https://www.lagomframework.com/) . It is a akka based framework (DDD for design).

Application is complete and working. See if that serve your purpose.